# How to get wave height in specific point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, shader-graph

I can't come up with how can I get wave height from my ocean shader created in the shader graph. I am thinking about using the time value set from the script instead of shader time to control it, but what should I do later? Try to get position on texture and try to figure out height value? I have no idea how can I bite it...

A part of my shader:

[image]

Comment: Or maybe I can synchronize a noise somehow with a script?